# Django to_html() update to allow users to select row

Tags: python, django

I am asking users to enter a string, and presenting them with some options to select from. These options are stored as a dataframe and I render them using the to_html() function. However, I cant find any information on how to edit the to_html() call to allow me to make it so the table can have selectable rows.

Everything else work lovely!

Here is relevant lines from views.py

```
def result(request):
  search_term=request.POST.get('q','')
  search_term=str(search_term)
  lkp = run_lkp(SearchString)
  result = []
  for l in lkp:
    result.append(dfCorpus.ix[l])
  df= result[0]  
  html_df=df.to_html(index=False)
  return render(request, 'result.html', {'html_df': html_df,'post_output': request.POST.get('q','')})
```

Here is result.html;

```
<html>
 <h1><strong>lookup</strong></h1> 
    <head>
        <title>select right one</title>
    </head>
<body>
<h3>You searched for:</h3>  {{ post_output }}
<h3>Your results:</h3> {{ html_df|safe }}
</body>
</html>
```

Im assuming this is possible, but I cant figure out how!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use

```
html_df=[v for k, v in df.T.to_dict().items()])
```

Then you can iterate over your the records in your template and use your own html, for example:

```
<table width="100%">    
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Fieldname</th>
        <th>Fieldname</th>
        <th>Fieldname</th>
        <th>Fieldname</th>
        <th>Fieldname</th>
    </tr>   
</thead>
<tbody>
    {% for item in html_df %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ item.fieldname }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.fieldname }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.fieldname }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.fieldname }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.fieldname }}</td>
    </tr>       
    {% empty %}
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5">No Records</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}                
</tbody>            
</table>
```

Comment: That's exactly what im looking for! thanks! This will now enable me to code the selectable part in html!